# Reading through File with temp file in C

Tags: c, file, for-loop

I'm trying to read through a text file and using a for loop to do so as follows:

```
FILE *in = fopen("sim_input.txt", "r");
FILE *temp = in;
for (char c = getc(temp); c != EOF; c = getc(temp))
{
    fscanf(in, "%d %d\n", &A[in].from, &A[in].to);
}
```

The problem is that the `getc()` is messing with the file stream and `fscanf()`. I tried creating a temp file to divert the stream but that didn't work.

The text file contains.

```
1 10
4 20
5 14
6 7
8 1
4 5
10 14
```

And it's coming out as:

```
10 4
1 5
4 6
etc
```

How can I stop this from happing.

Comment: regarding the expression: `char c = getc(temp);`  The function: `getc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`.  and depending on the `char` signness of your implementation, as a `char`, the `EOF` might not be recognized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
while (fscanf(in, "%d %d\n", &A[in].from, &A[in].to) != EOF)
{
  // empty block
}
```

or this:

```
do
{ 
  fscanf(in, "%d %d\n", &A[in].from, &A[in].to);
}
while (!feof(in));
```

Your attempt of using `temp` instead of `in` for the `getc` is pointless as `temp` and `in` refer to the exact same FILE object.

**Bonus hint**

Another thing that is absolutely essential is checking if `fopen` fails:

```
FILE *in = fopen("sim_input.txt", "r");
if (in == NULL)
{
  // take action if file could not be opened
}
else
{
  // process file
}
```

In your code if the file does not exist or cannot be opened for whatever other reason you will fscan from a NULL FILE pointer which usually doesn't end well.